# Creating a Button to evaluate initialization cells

Tags: front-end, evaluation, gui-construction

I am trying to create a setup where I have a number of `InputField`, `SetterBar`, and `Checkbox` with `Dynamic` in the first cell of my notebook where I can set some options/values, and then have a `Button` which executes the initialization cells once these parameters have been chosen.

I was trying to understand how to use `FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluateInitialization"]`, but when I put this in a cell and run it, I get the following output and the evaluation cells don't get executed, let alone when I put it inside of a `Button` (in which case nothing happens at all):

`RefLink[TextCell[ RawBoxes["FrontEndToken"]],  paclet : ref/FrontEndToken]["EvaluateInitialization"]`

which looks like this
[image]

---

Problem solved: I had copied and pasted the `FrontEndTokenExecute` out of the Mathematica documentation window and it copied as a hyperlink, thus the `RefLink`. Replacing it with plain text fixed it and the button works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button[Style["Before reading this notebook, press me", Bold, 
  Darker@Red], 
 FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["EvaluateInitialization"]]]
```